# The server tag is not well formed in html

Tags: html, asp.net

Why i getting this error here is my  code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit" Visible="True" >
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:LinkButton  ID="btnModemDetailsEdit  AccessibleHeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" runat="server" OnClick='btnModemDetailsEdit_Click'  runat="server"/>
  </ItemTemplate>                                  
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is caused by a missing "

Comment: Come on....the code formatting in the question highlights your issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <asp:LinkButton  ID="btnModemDetailsEdit"  AccessibleHeaderText="Edit" ButtonType="Button" Text="Edit" HeaderText="Edit" runat="server" OnClick="btnModemDetailsEdit_Click"  runat="server"/>
```

You were missing a quote for your ID value, and you were using an apostrophe as your delimiter for your OnClick attribute.